# How to see the telemetry of azure kubernetes having containers and images in Application Insights?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

I developed .net core web and API applications with Docker support using VS2017. And configured the application insights for both web and API applications through the VS 2017 by following this below links.

[Application Insights for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-core)

[Monitor Docker applications in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-docker#set-up-your-application-insights-resource)

[microsoft/applicationinsights](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/applicationinsights/)

I deployed the above containers into azure kubernetes and then browse those containers URL’s in my browser but I am not able to see the data related to those images and containers in Docker Tile on application insights dashboard.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you describe the issue with more details. You deployed apps to kubernetes, and you are not seeing telemetry about the apps in Azure portal? The docker image is for a Java application, but it seems you have asp.net core app?

Comment: @cijothomas, yes I deployed apps to kubernetes, then I am not able see the telemetry about the apps in the azure application insights portal.

Comment: I added the docker tile in application insights dashboard but I am not able to see the data like CPU usage, available memory etc.. related to containers, images deployed azure kubernetes.

Comment: For Asp.Net Core application you are using - how have you configured application insights? And where is instrumentation key stored. I'd start by making sure instrmentation key is correctly set when deploying to Docker. Also, asp.net core apps don't collect any perfcounters.

Comment: btw - were you able to see data before you deploy to kubernetes? i.e running locally? if yes, i'd suspect ikey is not setup correctly inside container.

Comment: @cijothomas, I added the instrumentation key under containers section in deployment file like `env:
        - name: APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
          value: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx`

Comment: I am able to see the data like page views, custom events, exceptions and requests etc... But I am unable to see the data for knowing status of containers like running and stop. And also i want to know the Perf counters by host, activity by image and Exceptions by container name.

Comment: Application Insights SDK for Asp.Net Core does not collect perf counters. It also does not have anything to collect container stats. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes - This can give you some more info about deployment, but nothing about perfcounter or docker stats

Comment: You can try Azure Diagnostics to get Docker stats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics-schema-1dot3-and-later#dockersources to get started. I've never tried this myself though.